# How to set Layer's options' title?

Tags: leaflet

How to set Layer's options' title? I want to identify each layer
[image]

```
 var overLayers = [
 {
   name: "Bar",
   icon: iconByName('bar'),
   layer: L.geoJson(Bar,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature}),
   group: "Bar",
   marekerType:"accordion",
   active:true,
 }
];
```

Comment: Could you kindly share more context for your issue? Is it a marker built from a GeoJSON?

Comment: Yes , thank  you for your reply. 

`var overLayers = [
 {
  name: "Bar",
  icon: iconByName('bar'),
  layer: L.geoJson(Bar,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature,options:{title:"aa"}}),
  group: "Bar",
  marekerType:"accordion",
  active:true,
 }
];`

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn how our focussed Q&A format works.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with any requested details.  Pictures cannot be searched, and so should not be used to provide code.

Comment: PolyGeo, Thank you very much. I will read it and reply to you all. I am new in here Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I set title in pointToLayer function.

```
 var overLayers = [
{
        name: "Bar",
        icon: iconByName('bar'),
        layer: L.geoJson(Bar,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature,pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
           title :'bar'
      });
        }}),
        group: "Bar",
        marekerType:"label",
      active:true,
  }
];
```